# Damping in Unity Shuriken Particle System

Tags: unity, particles

Is there no damping functionality in Unity Shuriken Particle? 
"Velocity Over Lifetime" is different from damping.

I try to find it on particle system, but can't.
Or is there any other way to apply particle damping?

I want to control each particle's velocity decrement?

**Update:** Add a poor art work :)

[image]

Comment: By damping, do you mean, slow down the number of particles being generated?

Comment: no, slowing down each particle's velocity.

Comment: If you do not want to slow it over the lifetime, but right out of the gate, you will need to update the properties from source code, since this would be an initial property that would need to be set prior to the particle being created.

Comment: Can you define more precisely what behaviour you want (images always help) and how it's different from what you can achieve with the velocity over lifetime modifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit Velocity Over Lifetime->Dampen in the Editor.

From Unity Docs: "(0-1) value that controls how much the exceeding velocity should be dampened. For example, a value of 0.5 will dampen exceeding velocity by 50%."

For best results set Speed under Limit Velocity Over Lifetime to a Curve that shows how you want the particles velocity to react over its lifetime then use Dampen to fine tune it to your liking.